# Iterating over lines (w/ numbers) read from a file to an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm trying to write a small script that will take the 4th columns of a file and store it in an array then do a little comparison. If the element in the array is greater than 0 and less than 500 I have to increment the counter. However when I run the script the counter always shows 0.  Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile -t my_array < <(cat file1.txt | awk '{ print $4 }' > test.txt)
COUNTER=0
for i in ${my_array[@]}; do
if [["${my_array[$i]}" -gt 0 -a "${my_array[$i]}" -lt 500 ]]
then
COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
fi
printf "%s\t%s\n" "%i" "${my_array[$i]}"//just to test if the mapfile command is working 
done
echo $COUNTER
```

output:

```
./script1.bash
0
```

Comment: You need a space after `[[`.  Also, you may not get anything into your `my_array` because the `awk` output is going to `test.txt`.

Comment: Double quote array subscripts, `for i in "${my_array[@]}";`

Comment: Make a habit of running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing everything it finds before asking questions here.

Comment: Redirecting `> test.txt` means content isn't going to stdout, so it's not being fed into mapfile.

Comment: If you did a `declare -p my_array` to check your array's contents, that would have made it obvious that it was empty.

Comment: @codeforester When running the script, printf gives the exact result.

Comment: @user3022048, it's not clear to me what you mean by that comment, or how you intend it to be a response to what codeforester said. Could you restate?

Comment: BTW, one thing I missed on first pass was the [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). There's no particular call for it here; `awk <file1.txt` or `awk file1.txt` is more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t my_array < <(awk '{ print $4 }' file1.txt | tee test.txt)
COUNTER=0
for idx in "${!my_array[@]}"; do
  value=${my_array[$idx]}
  if (( value > 0 )) && (( value < 500 )); then
    COUNTER=$((COUNTER + 1))
  fi
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$idx" "$value"
done
echo "$COUNTER"
```

- The use of `cat` here is needless: It added nothing but inefficiency (requiring an extra process to be started, and forcing awk to read from a pipe rather than direct from a file).
- `mapfile` had nothing to read because the output of `awk` was redirected to `test.txt`. If you want it to go to both a file *and* stdout, then you need to use `tee`.
- `-a` is not valid in `[[ ]]`; use `&&` instead there. However, since you're doing only arithmetic, `(( ))` is more appropriate. Incidentally, `-a` is officially marked obsolescent even for `[ ]` and `test`; see [the current POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).
- `${my_array[@]}` iterates over *values*. If you want to iterate over *indexes*, you need `${!my_array[@]}` instead.
- Whitespace is mandatory in separating command names. `[["$foo"` is a different command from `[[`, unless `$foo` is empty or starts with a character in $IFS.

Comment: If `test.txt` is not needed, then mapfile could be written as `mapfile -t my_array < <(awk '{ print $4 }' file1.txt)`.

Comment: Surprisingly `shellcheck` didn't catch the `-a is not valid in [[ ]]` part. Should have caught it!

Comment: @Inian Yes, it catches it, but only if some of the other issues are fixed, see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2108

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `&&` is valid inside `((...))`, although I don't know that using it there gets you anything other than saving the 4 keystrokes needed to close and reopen the arithmetic statements.

Comment: Nitpick: `-a` is not obsoleted (yet), it  [have been marked obsolescent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16), so, it will, just not yet.

Comment: @sorontar, ...*nod*. I was a bit careless there; updated appropriately.

Comment: @sorontar, I'm rolling back your edit: For `[[ ]]`, the original language of "is not valid" is correct. In both bash 3.2.57(1)-release and 4.4.5(1)-release, `[[ 1 -eq 1 -a 2 -eq 2 ]]` results in `syntax error in conditional expression`.

Comment: Sorry @CharlesDuffy. Yes, my mistake, you are correct, it is accepted only inside `[..]`. But even then, `[ 1 -eq 1 -a 2 -eq 2 ]` has more than 4 tokens and should be rejected following POSIX: `>4 arguments: The results are unspecified.`[A little before this link.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_06)

Comment: @sorontar, "unspecified" does not mean "forbidden" or "must be rejected"; it means just what it says, "unspecified". `echo -n` is unspecified. Passing any string with a backslash into `echo` makes its output unspecified. This doesn't mean that a POSIX-compliant implementation is obliged to reject these things; it simply means that POSIX does not strictly define behavior in the case where they are present.

Comment: @sorontar, moreover, behavior with more than four arguments is unspecified for *precisely the same reason* that `-a` is obsolescent: Because arguments with literal parenthesis are indistinguishable from grouping operators with ugly hacks such as `"x$foo"`; however, without `-a` or `-o`, there are no grouping operators, and thus there are also no valid uses with more than four arguments.

Comment: @sorontar, ...there are thus differing historical implementations of these corner cases, and instead of POSIX taking a position on how to resolve them, it just marks the routes by which those corner cases can be reached obsolescent and the outcome undefined, such that all historical implementations are equally compliant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I believe I understand the meaning of "unspecified". The use that I intent to transmit is that if something is unspecified, it could very well fail (and validly without any warning) and therefore: "**we** should reject its use or building new code with such unspecified results". Not that some program will or not process the code (even in unexpected ways). The comment was written with that thinking and intent in mind.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The grouping of options may still be needed to negate a group: [ ! ( FILE1 -nt FILE2 ) ] (shockingly: note that such simple construct has 6 tokens).

Comment: @sorontar, nope. `[ ! FILE1 -nt FILE2 ]` is entirely equivalent.

Comment: @sorontar, ...moreover, the case where `$1` is `!` and it's followed by a three-argument test is the *only* four-argument case that isn't either unspecified or obsolescent. There exist no non-obsolescent uses for `(` and `)` as grouping operators; `[ '(' unary ')' ]` is the only three-arg place they're valid, and it's a very *unfortunate* case, and obsolescent for good reason. (Consider `[ '(' = ')' ]` -- should it be false, because `(` and `)` differ, or true, because `=` is a non-empty string, and thus truthy as a unary operator?)

Answer (score 3):

If you redirect the output to a file: `> test.txt` then there is no output in "standard output" because it is consumed by the file. So, first, you need to remove that redirection. You may use:

```
mapfile -t my_array < <(cat file1.txt | awk '{ print $4 }' )
```

But since awk could perfectly well read a file, this is better:

```
mapfile -t my_array < <(awk '{ print $4 }' file1.txt)
```

And since you are using awk, it could do the comparison to 0 and 500 and output the whole count.

```
counter=$(awk '{if($4>0 && $4<500){c++}}END{print c}' file1.txt)
echo "$counter"
```

Simpler, faster.

That will also avoid some simple mistakes in your script, like missing an space in the `[…]` construct:

```
if [[ "${my …             # NOT "if [["${my …"
```

And some missing quotes:

```
for i in "${my_array[@]}"   # NOT for i in ${my_array[@]}
```

In general, it is a good idea to check your script with [ShellCheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to remove some simple mistakes.

Comment: Props for the point that this could all be done in one line of awk.